# Iframed page gives session expires when submitting form in IE and Safari

Tags: php, javascript, html, iframe, fancybox

Hi I'm using a third party order form on my website which is displayed by an iframe.
While using IE or Safari the iframe refuses to accept the form submit with an error box "session has expired"

The page is:
http://prepaidnuller.nl/gratisprepaid.php

If you click the bestel button you can just hit "volgende" below on the page and you'll get an error box which says that the session has expired (IE and Safari) other browsers do work.

When closing the iframe and then refreshing the page above manually and then retry to submit the form the whole thing is accepted though.

Any solutions on how IE and Safari could accept the form submit ? and do not display session expired.

Answer (score 0):

My bet?

[No DOCTYPE Declaration could be found or recognized in this document. This generally means that the document is not declaring its Document Type at the top. It can also mean that the DOCTYPE declaration contains a spelling error, or that it is not using the correct syntax.](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://prepaidnuller.nl/gratisprepaid.php)

Fancybox (like most of jQuery plugins) needs to run in standards mode, which means a proper `DOCTYPE` declaration has to be set.

Check [this good article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/) for more or simple set this as the first line of your document :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

BTW, since you are using fancybox v1.3.4 with ***inline*** content, beware of [THIS BUG](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/fancybox/-re22BoXOzM) and its workaround.